# org.apache.hadoop.fs.ParentNotDirectoryException: /tmp (is not a directory)

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am new to Hadoop and running wordCount2 example. however i am getting below error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.fs.ParentNotDirectoryException: /tmp (is not a directory)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkIsDirectory(FSPermissionChecker.java:570)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkSimpleTraverse(FSPermissionChecker.java:562)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkTraverse(FSPermissionChecker.java:537)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkTraverse(FSDirectory.java:1702)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkTraverse(FSDirectory.java:1720)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.resolvePath(FSDirectory.java:641)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.mkdirs(FSDirMkdirOp.java:51)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:2990)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1096)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:652)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:503)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:989)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:871)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:817)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2606)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:88)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:2474)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:2447)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$27.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1248)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$27.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirsInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:1245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSystem.java:1237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:161)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:150)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1570)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1567)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1567)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1588)
        at WordCount2.main(WordCount2.java:128)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:244)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:158)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.fs.ParentNotDirectoryException): /tmp (is not a directory)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkIsDirectory(FSPermissionChecker.java:570)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkSimpleTraverse(FSPermissionChecker.java:562)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkTraverse(FSPermissionChecker.java:537)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkTraverse(FSDirectory.java:1702)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkTraverse(FSDirectory.java:1720)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.resolvePath(FSDirectory.java:641)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.mkdirs(FSDirMkdirOp.java:51)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:2990)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1096)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:652)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:503)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:989)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:871)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:817)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2606)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1507)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1363)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:227)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:583)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:2472)
        ... 23 mor
```

**I can see the /tmp folder both in hdfs command as below**

```
hadoopusr@LAPTOP:~$ hdfs dfs -ls /
19/02/03 11:02:51 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 3 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoopusr supergroup          0 2019-02-03 08:34 /hadoopinput
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoopusr supergroup          0 2019-02-03 08:42 /sampledata
-rwxrwxrwx   1 hadoopusr supergroup      22594 2019-01-29 10:26 /tmp
```

**and even i can access the folder**

hadoopusr@LAPTOP:~$ cd /tmp/
hadoopusr@LAPTOP:/tmp$

I have installed hadoop 2.9.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 app in windows 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in your ls:

```
drwxr-xr-x - hadoopusr supergroup 0 2019-02-03 08:34 /hadoopinput 
drwxr-xr-x - hadoopusr supergroup 0 2019-02-03 08:42 /sampledata
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hadoopusr supergroup 22594 2019-01-29 10:26 /tmp
```

/tmp is not a directory because it is not prefixed by a d.

So rm this file (if not important) and make a directory both with the dfs command.